# Computing the integral $ \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x \,\mathrm{d} x}{\sqrt{2x^6+2x^3+1}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Compute the following integral
$$ \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x \,\mathrm{d} x}{\sqrt{2x^6+2x^3+1}}.$$
This integral obviously converges. However, is it computable?

Comment: Computable in what sense?  Closed form formula, maybe not.  Arbitrarily good rational approximations, certainly.

Comment: Numerically: sure, no problem. Analytically: no, I don't think so.

Comment: yes, I mean analytically computable.

Comment: begin with $u =  x^3 +\frac{1}{2} $  followed by $\sinh t = 2u$ Still a long slog with uncertain outcome

Answer (score 6):

The integral may be expressed in terms of elliptic integrals. Substitute $x=2^{-1/6}u$:
$$I=2^{-1/3}\int_{2^{1/6}}^\infty\frac u{\sqrt{u^6+\sqrt2u^3+1}}\,du$$
Then substitute $u+\frac1u=x$ (Byrd and Friedman 581.01) to get
$$I=2^{-4/3}\left(\int_y^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{(x-2)(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)}}\,dx+\int_y^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x+2)}}\,dx\right)$$
where $y=2^{1/6}+2^{-1/6}$, $a=\sqrt2$, $b=\frac{-\sqrt2+\sqrt6}2$ and $c=\frac{-\sqrt2-\sqrt6}2$. Finally use B&F 258.00… or rather this small modification of B&F 258.00: if $y>a>b>c>d$,
$$\int_y^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)}}\,dx=J(a,b,c,d,y)=gF(\varphi,m)$$
where $m=\frac{(b-c)(a-d)}{(a-c)(b-d)}$ is the parameter, $g=\frac2{\sqrt{(a-c)(b-d)}}$ and
$$\varphi=\sin^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{(a-c)(b-d)}}{\sqrt{(y-a)(y-b)}+\sqrt{(y-c)(y-d)}}$$
Then
$$I=2^{-4/3}(J(2,a,b,c,y)+J(a,b,c,-2,y))$$

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from mpmath import *
mp.dps = 100

print(quad(lambda x: x/sqrt(2*x**6 + 2*x**3 + 1), [1, inf]))

def bf258_00(a, b, c, d):
    y = root(2,6) + root(2,-6)
    g = 2 / sqrt((a-c)*(b-d))
    m = (b-c)*(a-d)/(a-c)/(b-d)
    s1 = sqrt((a-c)*(b-d))
    s2 = sqrt((y-a)*(y-b))
    s3 = sqrt((y-c)*(y-d))
    vphi = asin(s1 / (s2 + s3))
    return g * ellipf(vphi, m)

ra = sqrt(2)
rb = (-sqrt(2)+sqrt(6))/2
rc = (-sqrt(2)-sqrt(6))/2
I1 = bf258_00(2, ra, rb, rc)
I2 = bf258_00(ra, rb, rc, -2)
print(root(16, -3) * (I1 + I2))

0.632421879503014798952234566937018710345295154697941062278011824742339961706287315740337102826246671...
```

---

$I$ with bounds $[2^{-1/6},\infty]$ (note that $2^{-1/6}<1$) evaluates to $2^{-4/3}(J(2,a,b,c,2)+J(a,b,c,-2,2))$. $I$ with bounds $[0,2^{-1/6}]$ evaluates to $2^{-4/3}(J(2,a,b,c,2)-J(a,b,c,-2,2))$. Therefore $I$ with bounds $[0,\infty]$ requires only one elliptic integral:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac x{\sqrt{2x^6+2x^3+1}}\,dx=2^{-1/3}J(2,a,b,c,2)$$

Comment: *Of course*, elliptic integrals are "closed form"! Without so-called "special functions", we couldn't do very many integrals. They were invented exactly for that. :-)

Comment: For that matter the Appell hypergeometric functions are closed-forms as well. Whether you find them more obscure than elliptic integrals is a matter of taste (though I tend to agree with it).

Comment: Does this approach lead to a simple representation if the initial integral's lower limit is $x=0$ rather than $x=1$? Per my answer, this has a compact representation in terms of ${_2}F_1$ and I'm curious if the elliptic integral form is similarly elegant.

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes. In fact the $[0,\infty]$ integral only requires one $F$ rather than two in the given case. See edit.

Answer (score 4):

I have to share @RobertIsrael and @ProfessorVector's doubts.

Call it $I$. Following @WillJagy, take $2x^3+1=\sinh t$ so$$I=\frac{1}{3\sqrt[6]{2}}\int_{\operatorname{arsinh}3}^\infty(\sinh t-1)^{-1/3}\mathrm dt.$$Using [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28sinh+t-1%29%5E%28-1%2F3%29),$$I=2^{-5/3}[(\sinh t-1)^{2/3}\cosh t\cdot f(t)]_{\operatorname{arsinh}3}^\infty$$where$$f(t):=F_1(\tfrac23;\,\tfrac12,\,\tfrac12;\,\tfrac53;\,\tfrac12(1+i)(1-\sinh t),\,\tfrac12(1-i)(1-\sinh t)),$$with $F_1$ the [Appell hypergeometric function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html). Assuming the bracketed expression vanishes in the $t\to\infty$ limit (hopefully an expert on $F_1$ can weigh in on that),$$I=-\sqrt{\tfrac52}F_1(\tfrac23;\,\tfrac12,\,\tfrac12;\,\tfrac53;\,-1-i,\,-1+i).$$If *that* has a nicer closed form, I'd love to see it.

Comment: There's a nicer closed form. See my answer.

Comment: What I get from Mathematica (after integrating and simplifying under the assumption $t\geq 0$) is $$I=2^{-5/3}[(\sinh t-1)^{2/3}\cdot f(t)]_{\operatorname{arsinh}3}^\infty.$$

Comment: @Semiclassical I've fixed that for now; I'll privately review these coefficients.

Comment: Here's Mathematica code which verifies it: `FullSimplify[D[(-1 + Sinh[t])^(2/3)/(2 2^(2/3)) AppellF1[2/3, 1/2, 1/2, 5/3, (1 + I)/2 (1 - Sinh[t]), (1 - I)/2 (1 - Sinh[t])], t], t >= 0]`. Also, it looks like $f$ does vanish at infinity per your original hope.

Comment: ...but, having considered further: $f(t)$ does vanish at infinity, but $(\sinh t-1)^{2/3}$ doesn't, and it looks as if their product doesn't vanish at infinity. So the $t=\infty$ term can't be set aside so nicely...

Comment: @Semiclassical (Let alone the $\cosh t$.) That's probably why, if we multiply what I wrote before by $\sqrt[4]{2}$, you don't get what the other answer reports (ironically, it was closer before).

Comment: One other issue in this is that Mathematica doesn't seem very knowledgeable about Appell F1 identities. For instance, if I write the integration domain over $t$ analogously to in my answer, Mathematica does obtain results but doesn't recognize that they're equivalent to what I obtain by integrating over $v$.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more Mathematica legerdemain: If we substitute $v=2x^3+1$, we obtain the form

$$I=\frac{1}{3 \sqrt[6]{2}}\int_3^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{v-1}}\frac{dv}{\sqrt{1+v^2}}.$$
Writing the integration range as $\int_3^\infty = \int_1^\infty -\int_1^3$, Mathematica yields
$$I= \frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}{_2}F_1\left(\frac13,\frac56,1,-1\right)-  \frac12 F_1\left(\frac23;\frac12,\frac12;\frac53;-1+i,-1-i\right)$$
where ${_2}F_1(a,b;c;x)$ is the Gauss hypergeometric function and $F_1(a;b,c;d;x,y)$ is the Appell hyper-geometric function referenced in J.G.'s answer. Note that this means

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{x\,dx}{\sqrt{2x^6+2x^3+1}} &= \frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}{_2}F_1\left(\frac13,\frac56,1,-1\right),\\
\int_0^1 \frac{x\,dx}{\sqrt{2x^6+2x^3+1}} &= \frac12 F_1\left(\frac23;\frac12,\frac12;\frac53;-1+i,-1-i\right)
\end{align}

Mathematica can't simplify the first term further, but there's so many identities for hypergeometric functions that further simplification seems plausible. The Appell F1 term, however, seems rather impenetrable.